# Scraperjs interaction with the page

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

Somebody uses https://github.com/ruipgil/scraperjs for scraping web pages? 
I can not understand how to interact with the page? How to get google search results. This should be done as a function of scrape() or before?

Comment: I want to understand how to use the dynamic scraper find value in google and display the results. Here's how to phantomjs: 


**`page.evaluate(function() { $('#gbqfq').val("Test"); $("#gbqfba").click(); });`**

 Is it possible send the information to the server and parse the results?

Comment: I too am seeking this solution, this library/module is poorly documented, yet it is a great module.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) API. Scraperjs uses it for parsing. You can clarify here what do you wanna get from specific page and I will provide you with sample code.

Here is code for getting url from google query

```
var scraperjs = require('scraperjs')

scraperjs.StaticScraper
  .create('https://www.google.ru/search?q=scraperjs')
  .scrape(function($) {
    return $('li.g').map(function() {
      return $(this).find('a').first().attr('href')
    }).get();
  }, function(news) {
    news.forEach(function(elm) {
      console.log(elm);
    });
  });
```

~

Comment: thanks for the answer! I want to understand how to use the dynamic scraper find value in google and display the results. Here's how to phantomjs: **`page.evaluate(function() {                 $('#gbqfq').val("Test");                  $("#gbqfba").click();              });`**

Is it possible send the information to the server and parse the results?